# How to get only songs from itunes library with itlibrary.h

Tags: objective-c, itunes

This is the way the docs say to get all media items from library, however I want to get only the songs.

```
#import <iTunesLibrary/ITLibrary.h>

ITLibrary *library = [ITLibrary libraryWithAPIVersion:@"1.0" error:&error];
if (library)
{
    tracks = library.allMediaItems; //  <- NSArray of ITLibMediaItem
}
```

I found this answer: [How to get all tracks from an album using iTunes.h/Scripting Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076113/how-to-get-all-tracks-from-an-album-using-itunes-h-scripting-bridge)

I'm not sure how to adapt it to do what I need it to, or maybe it is less complicated now?

Comment: It seems that you still need to filter with a `NSPredicate`, looking for `tracks = [library.allMediaItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaKind == %d", ITLib​Media​Item​Media​Kind​Song]];`

Comment: works great thanks. I figured it might be the same, but I didn't know the new names of the kinds. If you make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: I just read the documentation of `ITLibMediaItem` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/ituneslibrary/itlibmediaitem?language=objc) and know how to use/construct a `NSPredicate`. Nothing complicate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracks = library.allMediaItems;` is a `NSArray` of [`ITLibMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/ituneslibrary/itlibmediaitem?language=objc) objects.

According to the doc, it as a property `mediaKind` that gives it the item is a song (`ITLib​Media​Item​Media​Kind​Song`) or another kind of media.

So, you just have to use the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaKind == %d", ITLib​Media​Item​Media​Kind​Song]]
```

So to filter (with previous predicate)

```
tracks = [library.allMediaItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```